# Mongoose schema for an array of objects and objects

Tags: rest, mongoose, postman, mongoose-schema

I am trying to build an E-commerce store backend and can't seem to get it right. I want to POST form datafor a customer to a mongo database which would contain details of his order as follows:

1. orderAmount: Number,
2. orderId: String,
3. orderedItems: Array of Objects which has the keys id(Mongoose Object Id), img(String), name(String),price(Number),quantity(Number),size(String)
4. customerDetails: An object with keys name(String), email(String), contact(String), city:(String), street(String),postal(String)

What I expect in response:

```
{
  "orderAmount": "2343.96",
  "orderId": "EO25081",
  "orderedItems": "[{id: "6491ae2210a89ad9cb7b423d",img:"https://i.imgur.com/DWj9i4D.jpg",name: "GAME OVER",price: 1299,quantity: 2,size: "L"}]",
  "customer": "{name: "sam",email: "sam@gmail",contact: "2323232323",city: "xyz",street: "asdfasdfasdf",postal: "123456"}"
}
```

What I've tried:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  orderAmount: { type: Number },
  orderId: { type: String },
  orderedItems: [
    {
      id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" },
      img: { type: String },
      name: { type: String },
      price: { type: Number },
      quantity: { type: Number },
      size: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  customer: {
    type: {
      name: { type: String },
      email: { type: String },
      contact: { type: String },
      city: { type: String },
      street: { type: String },
      postal: { type: String },
    },
  },
});

export const Customer = mongoose.model("Customer", schema);
```

Request body I'm sending in Postman:

```
{
  "orderAmount": "2343.96",
  "orderId": "EO25081",
  "orderedItems": "[{id: \"6491ae2210a89ad9cb7b423d\",img:\"https://i.imgur.com/DWj9i4D.jpg\",name: \"GAME OVER\",price: 1299,quantity: 2,size: \"L\"}]",
  "customer": "{name: \"Sam\",email: \"sam@gmail\",contact: \"2323232323\",city: \"xyz\",street: \"asdfasdfasdf\",postal: \"123456\"}"
}
```

I get the message :

> {
> "message": "Customer validation failed: orderedItems: Cast to embedded failed for value "[{id: "6491ae2210a89ad9cb7b423d",img:"https://i.imgur.com/DWj9i4D.jpg",name: "GAME OVER",price: 1299,quantity: 2,size: "L"}]" (type string) at path "orderedItems" because of "ObjectParameterError", customer: Cast to Embedded failed for value "{name: "Sarthak",email: "sarthaksam@gmail",contact: "7838711476",city: "delhi",street: "asdfasdfasdf",postal: "110075"}" (type string) at path "customer" because of "ObjectExpectedError""
> }

Any advice? I'm pretty new to all this so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something very weird or silly.